# Retrieving amount of words from a HTML document

Tags: javascript, html, ruby

I'm trying to retrieve the first 10 words from a HTML encoded string.

At the moment i'm splitting by whitespace. the problem is that whitespaces in the arguments of the tags gets recognized as separate words aswell.

I need a mechanism which gives me back a correctly formatted preview of a HTML Document as a string in Ruby or JavaScript.

Anybody has an idea?

Allowed in the HTML String are lists, paragraphs, colors, etc. But nothing exotic like forms, radios, iframes, tables or flash

Comment: can you give an example for the string?

Comment: You will need to use a html parser to do it.. a simple string processing may not give you the result you are looking for

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t0xntsyh/5/ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this job in Ruby, you can use Nokogiri gem. It is perfect for your job. [Here](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html) you have some examples of how to use it. Nokogiri is well documented and easy to use.